# CSS: How to put text in a circle with a hover effect?

Tags: css

Jfiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/qd2o38fp/

Basically, all I want to do right now is place a big letter "P" on the background but I'm not sure how to do that. All the hover effect is down (which I got from online)

```
<ul class="ch-grid">
    <li>
        <div class="ch-item ch-img-1">
            <div class="ch-info">
                <h3>See Portfolio</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qd2o38fp/1/ ?

Comment: thank you!! you just added 'content: p' ?

Comment: I also removed an unnecessary `:before` rule.